# Will I lose IK constraints when transferring models from Blender to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I've been working in blender making a simple character with an armature object controlling its limbs and movements and such. It has IK constraints as well for knees bending and I plan on making it for arms too. The question I have is, when I bring this model into Unity, will I lose the armature, and with it the IK stuff as well?

Comment: Have you tried? Probably faster than writing this question ^^

Comment: This question took me about 1 minute to make, but no I hadn't tried because I was not done making the model and realized that if I couldn't use the armature rig I was making in Blender then it would just be a big waste of time, so I figured I would make sure first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will loose the ik constraints. Mainly because unity doesn't even have ik support without any packages, so you need to recreate the ik in unity. Maybe look into the official animation rigging package by unity.